# Disable logging of requests from certain IPs apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, logging, configuration, apache2

I wan't to stop logging accesses from two of my local IPs, this is what I added to `apache2.conf`:

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
  SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192.168.0.1" dontlog
  SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192.168.0.192" dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Accesses from those two IPs still show up in my `access.log`:

`192.168.0.192 - - [31/Jan/2019:21:52:10 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5859 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"`

It has been asked how to disable logging of certain IPs on this site a lot, but all questions were more or less answered by the approach above, but I still can't figure it out for the life of me. How can I get this to work or where can I see what's wrong? `error.log` doesn't show any syntax errors, only the usual logs it produces on startup.

Yes, I have restarted apache after changing the file and it is up and running:

```
Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-01-31 21:52:07 CET; 12min ago
```

---

Edit: `apache2ctl -M` shows that `setenvif_module (shared)` is enabled.

---

Edit 2: I don't know if this is relevant but in my `apache2.conf` following line exists:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```